# JPA2 Criteria Query to select records in Table A whose reference is not found in Table B

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, jpa-2.0

I have the following tables with the following structure

```
Table A {
    id <-- Primary key
    someColumn 
}

Table B {
    id <-- Primary key
    someColumn 
    idOfA <-- Foreign key mapping to Table A
}
```

Entity classes look like below

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "A")
public class A implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -78448557049178402L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    .......
    .......
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "a")
    private List<B> bs = new ArrayList<>();
}

@Entity
@Table(name = "B")
public class B implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -659500557015441771L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    .......
    .......
    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "a_id", nullable = false)
    private A a;
 }
```

Using JPA2, I want to select records from table A which do not have a reference in Table B.

The Expected native postgres query is

```
select * from A a 
    where a.id not in 
        (select b.idOfA from B b);
```

What I have so far managed to do is

```
public List<A> getANotInB() {
    CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();


    // Select From Table B
    CriteriaQuery<B> criteriaQueryB = criteriaBuilder
            .createQuery(B.class);
    Root<B> rootB = criteriaQueryB.from(B.class);
    criteriaQueryB.select(rootB);

    // Select records from Table A
    CriteriaQuery<A> criteriaQueryA = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> rootA = criteriaQueryA.from(A.class);
    criteriaQueryA.select(A);

    // Create predicate   
    Predicate predicate = rootAttemptA.in(criteriaQueryB.getSelection());
    criteriaQueryA.where(criteriaBuilder.not(predicate));

    // Create query

    TypedQuery<A> query = entityManager.createQuery(criteriaQueryA);
    List<A> as= query.getResultList();
    System.out.println(as);
    return as;
}
```

I know the code above is incorrect and I have got a lot of basics wong.
Kindly help

Note: I Want to use JPA2 Criteria Query

Comment: Show your A and B class, it should configured mapping before you can join with JPA Criteria

Comment: Added Entity classes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get it done using subquery() as below. Posting it so that it can help others

```
CriteriaBuilder criteriaBuilder = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

// select a from A a 
CriteriaQuery<A> queryA = criteriaBuilder.createQuery(A.class);
Root<A> rootA = queryA.from(A.class);
queryA.select(rootA);

// Select distinct aId from B
CriteriaQuery<B> subQueryB = queryA.subquery(B.class);
Root<B> rootB = subQueryB.from(B.class);
bQuery.select(rootB.get("a")).distinct(true);

queryA.where(criteriaBuilder.not(criteriaBuilder.in(rootA.get("id").value(subQueryB))));

TypedQuery<A> query = entityManager.createQuery(aQuery);
List<A> result = query.getResultList();
```

Thanks @Mạnh for showing the way

Comment: I might be wrong but the CriteriaQuery<B> subQueryB = queryA.subquery(B.class); looks wrong to me. It has to be assigned on a Subquery<B>

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
    CriteriaBuilder cb = entityManager.getCriteriaBuilder();

    // Select distinct aid from B
    CriteriaQuery<B> bQuery = cb.createQuery(B.class);
    Root<B> bRoot = bQuery.from(B.class);
    bQuery.select(bRoot.get("a").get("id")).distinct(true);

    // Select * from A where aid not in ()
    CriteriaQuery<A> aQuery = cb.createQuery(A.class);
    Root<A> aRoot = aQuery.from(A.class);
    aQuery.select(aRoot).where(cb.not(aRoot.get("id").in(bQuery)));

    TypedQuery<A> query = entityManager.createQuery(aQuery);
    List<A> result = query.getResultList();
```

Basically, you will construct part of the query and glue them together.

More information here:

[JPA Criteria](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/persistence-criteria003.htm#GJIVM)